# Get Facebook Events in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, events

I have created an Android Application in that I want to get Facebook Events using Graph API.

So now I can get only Admin and Developer's events, I can't get other users events.

So what can I do for getting other users events.

My Code is:

```
new Request(
    session,
    "/" + user.getId() + "/events",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
            Log.v("response", "event : " + response);
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the facebook docs. Your application need to go through review to be able to request the `user_events` permission to non-admins/developers/testers:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/overview

Comment: I added the permission using -  fbLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_events", "friends_events");

Comment: I can get the events when I login using my credentials, if I login using other user I can't get the events.

Comment: Have you read the docs I linked? That's exacly the behavior one would expect if your app hasn't been reviewed yet! And `friends_events` is no longer working. Read the docs.

Comment: Ok sir, I will check.

Comment: Sir how to post event in Facebook via android app, what is the best method ?

Comment: You cannot create events via the Graph API

Comment: Sir is there any parameter for getting Latitude and Longitude of Event?

Comment: Hello Sir, I successfully gets the Events but there are one problem, I wants to find events by area of radius, so for that I need Latitude - Longitude, so how to get Latitude and Longitude with Event?